# nethogs shows suspicious ip adresses

Tags: ubuntu

When I ran nethogs on my Ubuntu desktop I get among other such logs:
? root 192.168.178.29:43068-13.32.99.96:443
? root 192.168.178.29:57928-91.198.174.208:443
? root 192.168.178.29:80-192.168.178.1:33595
I don't know the ip address 192.168.178.29 and this ip doesn't fit to my current country.
I'm not sure weather it's something malicious or just an Ubuntu thing and would be really glad if someone could explain to me what it's all about and weather my system is somehow compromised.

Answer (score 0):

192.168.0.0/16 is private address space and should be local to your network.